# Adding Workflow as WCF Service reference to website. Business objects inside WCF are also exposed unnecesarrily

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, workflowservice

My solution has B2BobjectDLL, Web application and a Workflow as WCF service projects. Both Workflow wcf and web application had B2Bobject referenced. So when adding workflow WCF reference to my webapplication, It correctly exposes GetTossCardData method.

Toss class below i used is a B2BobjectDLL.

```
Toss toss = new Toss();
toss.GameID = 123;
string tossCardData = string.empty; 
tossCardData = tossCardService.GetTossCardData(toss, "10");
```

The problem is GetTossCardData has to take B2BobjectDLL class object toss, but the method is telling that we have to input tossCardService service's toss object.

Object browser window tells that the WF WCF project is exposing the same B2BobjectDLL class objects as its service object unnecessarily.

The error message is

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'B2BBusinessObjects.Toss' to 'SignalRServerNew.ServiceReference2.Toss'
```

How to restrict the exposed object or why it is wrongly exposed as different class ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a service reference, what happens is that VS runs a tool for you, named svcutil,  to generate proxy classes using the WSDL exposed by your "workflow" as a service, which is basically just another WCF service.

When you added the service reference, you could specify that you want certain types in certain assemblies "reused" - what that means is that the tool should not generate new classes for those types, but instead should create the proxy classes in such a manner that they will expect those reused types.

In your case, you want to tell VS to reuse the types in your references assembly B2BobjectDLL.

Judging by the error message you provided, i can conclude that this reuse didn't happen, because your generated proxy classes in the clr namepsace SignalRServerNew.ServiceReference2, expect objects with the same namespace, because that's how they were generated.

What you should do is:

1. Delete your current service reference and make sure no trace of it is left.
2. Add a new service referece, and make sure that you specify to reuse types from your assembly ( there should be an "advanced" button in the lower left corner of the "add service reference" window in visual studio.
3. (optional) - get an actual glimpse in the generated file to see for yourself how the proxy classes were generated.

Hope that helps.